# Discord.js missing access permision what should do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've my own bot but last 2 days I got this error I don't know why? Maybe some command but my bot only can send message and embed message that's why not more permission i don't think so it needed.
Or how can I show which permission is needed?

```js
/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349:13)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async MessageManager.react (/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/MessageManager.js:193:5)
    at async Message.react (/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:720:5) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/channels/855192585206366221/messages/919613273811333160/reactions/%E2%9C%85/@me',
 npm start

> TruthOrDarejs@1.0.0 start /home/runner/TruthOrDarejs
> node .

Server is ready.
DB connection sucessfull
Truth Or Dare#7260 Has logged in
/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async GuildInviteManager.create (/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildInviteManager.js:185:20)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/TruthOrDarejs/index.js:298:20) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/913210496147132479/invites',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      temporary: false,
      max_age: 0,
      max_uses: 0,
      unique: undefined,
      target_user_id: null,
      target_application_id: undefined,
      target_type: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! TruthOrDarejs@1.0.0 start: `node .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the TruthOrDarejs@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-12-12T16_48_03_527Z-debug.log
```

I added some new permission in the dev portal. but still it gets the error :(

Comment: Try giving the bots role the "create invite" permission

Comment: @Finbar oh yeah an couple of hours ago i added a bot log there bot gives me that server link it joined. In scope which permission should i give it?

Comment: Its not a scope, its a role permission. You should check in your code if the bot has the required permissions in the first place before trying to run anything.

Comment: In dev portal there is a permission "create instant invite" I selected this

Comment: Alright, well in one of your servers most likely someone denied this permission. So check if the bot has permission before running any code.

Comment: @Finbar What is the connection between one of my server?

Comment: @MobRule, reinvite the bot in your server but select the right permissions this time

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about discord permissions rather than programming

Comment: @Finbar ok i will do it